# URL Rewrite - Internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I want to change the current url `www.website.com/books.php?tk=3ba89ffd` to `www.website.com/books/3ba89ffd` but my htaccess file gives me an internal server error. I am using WAMP
Rewrite module is on.

Here is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}!-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}!-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}!-l

RewriteRule ^/books/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /books.php?tk=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax issues with your `RewriteCond` and then in pattern you need to take off leading slash as you're doing it in .htaccess.

Have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^books/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /books.php?tk=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you can't set options in your `.htaccess` file. Remove that line and set the value in your vhost.

And perhaps set the `-MultiViews` option.

Comment: yup thanks adding that line solves my problem also as @anubhava answered. Thanks!